# mysql query returning NULL for one column values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql database where I want to search for rows that satisfy a certain condition.
For that, I'm using the LIKE command, until here, all fine. However, there's a column that is showing its rows values as NULL. This only happens when I SELECT 3 of the 3 float column values. Below I leave pictures of the queries and the shown results.

CODE:

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `priceDose`, `priceHalfDose`, `priceQuarterDose` FROM `weekendmeals` WHERE `name` LIKE "%porco%"
```

RESULT:

```
=================================================================
| id | name                 | priceDose | priceHalfDose |       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 45 | Entrecosto de Porco  |      9.20 |          4.80 | NULL  |   
| 46 | Costelinhas de Porco |     12.30 |          6.90 | NULL  |
| 50 | Costelinhas de Porco |     12.30 |          6.90 | NULL  |
=================================================================
```

[Picture showing the bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhTaF.png)

CODE:

```
 SELECT `id`, `name`, `priceDose`, `priceQuarterDose` 
 FROM `weekendmeals` 
 WHERE `name` LIKE "%porco%"
```

RESULT:

```
============================================================
| id | name                 | priceDose | priceQuarterDose |
------------------------------------------------------------
| 45 | Entrecosto de Porco  |      9.20 |          0.00    |   
| 46 | Costelinhas de Porco |     12.30 |          0.00    |
| 50 | Costelinhas de Porco |     12.30 |          0.00    |
============================================================
```

[Result when I remove one of the -float values- column from the search query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwTtZ.png)

As you can see, the results are correctly shown when there are only 1 or 2 float columns in the search query, but when I SELECT all the 3 necessary columns of float values, one of them doesn't show, and the values of the rows are NULL.

Thanks in advance for any help. If you need extra explanation/data feel free to ask :)

Comment: Put the SQL IN the question, not a picture of it. Generally, we won't bother looking at linked pictures of code.

Comment: done. thanks for the reply

Comment: Where is the results?

Comment: In the pictures. It's hard to explain by words more than what is already written in the question

Comment: Well, can't help from pictures. you need to put the sql, and the results, from both sql queries, IN the question.

Comment: does the same thing happen if you use another sql client (e.g. command line, or workbench)? could be something odd in phpmyadmin. also is there a horizontal scrollbar at all?

Comment: @CharlesBretana i looked at the pictures and it genuinely is a bit difficult to explain without them. The column heading is missing apparently but it could just be a quirk of the phpmyadmin layout or something

Comment: @AngeloTeixeira what is the data-type you have set for priceQuarterDose

Comment: Strange. In the first picture the column doesn't even have a title. Maybe some unseen character somewhere, e.g. `priceHalfDose,`and  `priceQuarterDose` where we only suppose a blank? Do you get a column title when you enlarge the col width with your mouse? (I think the pictures are very helpful here, by the way.)

Comment: Try to run the query in mysql command line interface and paste the result of CLI. Sometimes phpmyadmin behaves strange

Comment: all the "price" columnns are float(10,2) data-type
when i enlarge it does nothing, it's like it has no name
there is no scrollbar

Comment: in the cli, the result is correct, all three columns show correct values. anyone knows why phpmyadmin is having trouble?

Comment: Probably just a visual or layout glitch. You could inspect the HTML source of the result page and see if the column heading is in the HTML table but just not visible for some reason. Also, what happens if you run the query but your browser window is significantly bigger / smaller? What happens if you change the order e.g. SELECT `priceQuarterDose`, `priceDose`, `priceHalfDose`, `id`, `name` etc?

Comment: Changed the order of columns and it showed results correctly, executed the initial query after it and it showed correctly. It's just a bug after all

Comment: a bug in what? The web server? the browser? the html generation engine in the php web code? It sounds like something on which I'd want a more definitive answer.

Comment: that's something I cannot know. This is what I did.
-Executed normal query (same as the first one in the question) in phpmyadmin -> returned bad result (same as in question)

-executed normal query in CLI -> good result

-executed normal query back in phpmyadmin ->bad result

-executed the query swapping column names order -> good result

-executed normal query (first one) -> good result (twice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all it was just a phpmyadmin bug, read the question's comments for more info.